# How do I move the \fboxsep in the middle

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I am trying to create these number bonds with squares for the numbers but I am not sure how to move the box towards the middle.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol,xcolor}
\fboxsep=4mm \fboxrule=0.5mm % set these parameters globally

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $2 + \fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null} = 5$
\item $\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null} + 2 = 5$

\item $1 + \fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null} = 5$
\item $\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null} + 1 = 5$

\item $3 + \fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null} = 5$
\item $\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null} + 3 = 5$
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding instructions to make your code minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

Comment: While it's (of course!) ok to upvote helpful answers immediately, site guidelines explicitly discourage users from "accepting" the first answer that comes along more or less immediately. For by waiting several hours or, ideally, a day or two, before accepting the most helpful answer, you don't discourage other would-be answer providers from posting additional, and possibly even more helpful, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a phantom of a symbol that's centered along the math axis, such as `\sum` and, to get a square, measure its height plus depth. Finally, decide about the value of `\fboxsep` to get the desired width of the square.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol}

\fboxsep=4mm \fboxrule=0.5mm % set these parameters globally

\newcommand{\fillnumber}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1mm}%
  \sbox0{$\sum$}%
  \fbox{$\vphantom{\sum}$\hspace{\dimeval{\ht0+\dp0}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $2 + \fillnumber = 5$
\item $\fillnumber + 2 = 5$

\item $1 + \fillnumber = 5$
\item $\fillnumber + 1 = 5$

\item $3 + \fillnumber = 5$
\item $\fillnumber + 3 = 5$
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `tasks` is, in my opinion, better than `multicols`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\fboxsep=4mm \fboxrule=0.5mm % set these parameters globally

\newcommand{\fillnumber}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1mm}%
  \sbox0{$\sum$}%
  \fbox{$\vphantom{\sum}$\hspace{\dimeval{\ht0+\dp0}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $2 + \fillnumber = 5$
\task $\fillnumber + 2 = 5$
\task $1 + \fillnumber = 5$
\task $\fillnumber + 1 = 5$
\task $3 + \fillnumber = 5$
\task $\fillnumber + 3 = 5$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `\null` as it doesn't have any *height*. Instead, set a `\phantom` number; it'll allow you to have a box that roughly matches the size of the contents. Also, define a command that can do all of the adjustments for you; this will make global changes much more easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol,enumitem}

\newcommand{\boxnum}[1]{{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{4mm}%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
  \fbox{\phantom{#1}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item $2 + \boxnum{3} = 5$
    \item $\boxnum{3} + 2 = 5$

    \item $1 + \boxnum{4} = 5$
    \item $\boxnum{4} + 1 = 5$

    \item $3 + \boxnum{2} = 5$
    \item $\boxnum{2} + 3 = 5$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Comment: This approach ends up enlarging the frameboxes relative to the OP's setup. Is there a way of avoiding enlarging the frameboxes?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that by "move the box towards the middle", you want the boxes to be *vertically centered* on the math axis. (Aside: The math axis is an invisible horizontal line that bisects symbols such as `-`, `=`, and `+`.) Moreover, I will assume that you'd like to achieve this goal *without* enlarging the frameboxes.

If these assumptions are correct, I suggest you encase the frameboxes in `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` wrappers; `\vcenter` is a command that centers its argument vertically on the math axis.

By the way, I think it's easier to write `\boxed{}` than `\fcolorbox{black}{white}{\null}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,multicol,xcolor,amsmath}
\fboxsep=4mm \fboxrule=0.5mm
\newcommand\mybox{%
   \vcenter{\hbox{$\boxed{}$}}} % feel free to come up with a snazzier name
\begin{document}

\noindent \textcolor{red}{Before}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $2 + \boxed{} = 5$
\item $\boxed{} + 2 = 5$

\item $1 + \boxed{} = 5$
\item $\boxed{} + 1 = 5$

\item $3 + \boxed{} = 5$
\item $\boxed{} + 3 = 5$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\bigskip
\noindent \textcolor{red}{After}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $2 + \mybox = 5$
\item $\mybox + 2 = 5$

\item $1 + \mybox = 5$
\item $\mybox + 1 = 5$

\item $3 + \mybox = 5$
\item $\mybox + 3 = 5$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```